# How to efficiently write a vector of structs to file?

Tags: c++, vector, struct

I have code that is writing a vector of size greater than 10million to a text file.  I used clock() to time the writefile function and its the slowest part of my program.  Is there a better way to write to file than my below method?

```
void writefile(vector<fields>& fieldsvec, ofstream& sigfile, ofstream& noisefile)
/* Writes clean and noise data to respective files
 *
 * fieldsvec: vector of clean data
 * noisevec: vector of noise data
 * sigfile: file to store clean data
 * noisefile: file to store noise data
 */
{
    for(unsigned int i=0; i<fieldsvec.size(); i++)
    {
        if(fieldsvec[i].nflag==false)
        {
            sigfile << fieldsvec[i].timestamp << ";" << fieldsvec[i].price << ";" << fieldsvec[i].units;
            sigfile << endl;
        }
        else
        {
            noisefile << fieldsvec[i].timestamp << ";" << fieldsvec[i].price << ";" << fieldsvec[i].units;
            noisefile << endl;
        }
    }
}
```

where my struct is:

```
struct fields
// Stores a parsed line of a file
{
public:
    string timestamp;
    float price;
    float units;
    bool nflag; //flag if noise (TRUE=NOISE)
};
```

Comment: YOu could fall-back to the old C i/o functions for fread/fwrite and see if that is faster?

Comment: I bet that "fprintf()" would be a lot faster than `ostream` - unfortunately, it will require some re-writing, using "FILE *" instead of "ostream&" as the input to the function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest getting rid of the `endl`. This effectively flushes the buffer every time and thus greatly increases the number of syscalls.

Writing `'\n'` instead of `endl` should be a very good improvement.

And by the way, the code can be simplified:

```
ofstream& files[2] = { sigfile, noisefile };
for(unsigned int i=0; i<fieldsvec.size(); i++)
  files[fieldsvec[i].nflag] << fieldsvec[i].timestamp << ';' << fieldsvec[i].price << ";\n";
```

Comment: @riotburn: I am very interested in hearing about your timing results with your unmodified code with only the `std::endl` changed to `'\n'`.  Also note that ipc recommended the ***character*** `'\n'`, not the `const char*` of a `"\n"`.  Please let us know what sort of difference just that change makes!

Comment: So before any changes, writefile took 107.8 seconds.  With "\n" it now takes 41.8 seconds!  With '\n' it takes 40.63 seconds.  What a difference!  @ipc I tried to use your clever idea of storing the files in an array but I got the following error: scrub.cpp:174:22: error: declaration of ‘files’ as array of reference

Comment: My VM was getting sluggish since I've had it open for a while so I rebooted it and I'm getting 35 seconds for the writefile function. So the results may have been a little skewed but its a butt load faster. Now its my fastest function, so I'm gonna work on speeding up the read and filtering function.

Answer (score 1):

You could write your file in binary format instead of text format to increase the writing speed, as suggested in [the first answer of this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13335749/writing-a-lot-of-txt-files-90-5mb-per-file-takes-up-to-1400s):

```
file.open(filename.c_str(), ios_base::binary);
...
// The following writes a vector into a file in binary format
vector<double> v;
const char* pointer = reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&v[0]);
size_t bytes = v.size() * sizeof(v[0]);
file.write(pointer, bytes);
```

From the same link, the OP reported:

- replacing std::endl with \n increased his code speed by 1%
- concatenating all the content to be written in a stream and writing everything in the file at the end increased the code speed by 7%
- the change of text format to binary format increased his code speed by 90%.

Comment: @riotburn:  Also very interested in hearing what sort of performance increase you get using binary I/O instead of text, as Etienne suggests!  Please let us know!

Comment: This is a good suggestion but unfortunately I have to leave it in text format.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A significant speed-killer is that you are converting your numbers to text.

As for the raw file output, the buffering on an `ofstream` is supposed to be pretty efficient by default.

You should pass your array as a const reference.  That might not be a big deal, but it does allow certain compiler optimizations.

If you think the stream is messing things up because of repeated writes, you could try creating a string with `sprintf` of `snprintf` and write it once.  Only do this if your timestamp is a known size.  Of course, that would make extra copying because the string must be then put in the output buffer.  Experiment.

Otherwise, it's going to start getting dirty.  When you need to tweak out the performance of files, you need to start tailoring the buffers to your application.  That tends to get down to using no buffering or cache, sector-aligning your own buffer, and writing large chunks.